# Встроить Flash с чужого сайта

Tags: flash

Здравствуйте
Плохо знаю Flash. Подскажите пожалуйста, как отобразить на странице своего сайта флэш, чтобы источник был сторонний сайт. хотелось бы взять вот по этой ссылке http://www.kia.ru/models/picanto/configurator, если первый шаг заполнить, на втором будет крутящийся автомобиль, как его забрать?

Answer (score 1):

В онлайн режиме очень сложно. Технически просто вытащить данные из SWF файла и воспроизвести у себя. Если же данные динамические то практическая сложность растет в разы. Тут есть только вариант со взломом протокола данных и написанием собственного движка для отображения машинки(машинок). Если же данные закрыты для внешних SWF хостов, то опять все становится еще сложнее для взлома.